# Grails Include template from external location

Tags: grails

How do I include external GSPs or template in the GSP file when the template to be included is not under views folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can easily do that. Here you go:

```
import grails.gsp.PageRenderer

class MyLib {

    static namespace = "foo"
    static defaultEncodeAs = "raw"

    PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer

    def externalTemplate = { attrs, body ->
        String externalFilePath = attrs.externalPath

        /*
         * Put content of that external template to a file inside grails-app/views folder
         * with a temporary unique name appended by current timestamp
         */
        String temporaryFileName = "_external-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".gsp"

        File temporaryFile = new File("./grails-app/views/temp/$temporaryFileName")

        /*
         * Copy content of external file path to the temporary file in views folder.
         * This is required since the groovyPageRenderer can compile any GSP located inside
         * the views folder.
         */
        temporaryFile.text << new File(externalFilePath).text

        /*
         * Now compile the content of the external GSP code and render it
         */
        out << groovyPageRenderer.render([template: "/temp/$temporaryFileName", model: attrs.model])

        // Delete the file finally
        temporaryFile.delete()
    }
}
```

Now in your actual GSP where you want to include the external GSP, you can write so:

```
<body>
    <foo:externalTemplate externalPath="/home/user/anyExternalFile.gsp" model="${[status: 1}" />
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I ended up using ajax.load to load the content.But your solution would also work.Will keep this in mind

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late for this reply but I encountered this problem when we tried to put report views outside of the views folder.

We couldn't use the above method because we are running a jar package and we couldn't create files inside views folder.

Here is the solution on Grails 4

first inject

```
def groovyPagesTemplateEngine
def groovyPageLayoutFinder
```

then in your controller

```
File externalFile = new File("/path/to/file.gsp")

if(externalFile && externalFile.exists()){
     GroovyPageView groovyPageView = new GroovyPageView()
     LinkedHashMap model = [:]
     Template template = groovyPagesTemplateEngine.createTemplate(externalFile.text, externalFileName)

     groovyPageView.setServletContext(getServletContext())
     groovyPageView.setTemplate(template)
     groovyPageView.setApplicationContext(getApplicationContext())
     groovyPageView.setTemplateEngine(groovyPagesTemplateEngine)
     groovyPageView.afterPropertiesSet()
     request.setAttribute GrailsLayoutDecoratorMapper.LAYOUT_ATTRIBUTE, null
     GrailsLayoutView grailsLayoutView = new GrailsLayoutView(groovyPageLayoutFinder, groovyPageView)
     grailsLayoutView.render model, webRequest.getCurrentRequest(), webRequest.getResponse()
     webRequest.renderView = false
     return
}
else {
     // something that shows error
     render "not found"
}
```